# Find a resource that is missing OSX

Tags: find, zsh, macos

On OSX (big sur -so Zhell)I have a folder that contains  .bundle files , each bundle containa several  files and folders.  in most of the files there is a resource called PNG_.zip and some   do not.

so if i run this :

```
find ~/Desktop/test  -name "PNG_.zip"
```

it will output  anything that contains   PNG_.zip .

I want however to find all the items that **do not contain PNG_.zip** how can i do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using zsh [glob qualifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers), assuming that the bundles are directories.

First, here's how to look for bundle directories anywhere under the current directory:

```
print -rC1 -- **/*.bundle(/N)
```

- `**/…` matches files in nested subdirectories.
- `(/)` restricts the matches to directories.
- `(N)` results in an empty list instead of erroring out if there are no matches.

Then filter the results to only retain the bundles without `PNG_.zip` anywhere:

```
print -rC1 -- **/*.bundle(/Ne['()(($#==0)) $REPLY/**/PNG_.zip(NDY1)'])
```

- `(e['…'])` filters the matches: only those for which the expression is true are retained. The code is executed for each match in turn, with `$REPLY` set to the match.
- `()(($#==0)) …` tests if `…` expands to a list of words with length 0, i.e. if `…` (as a list of words) is empty.
- `(Y1)` is an optimization to stop traversing the directory as soon as 1 match is found. `(D)` (`dotglob`) is to also look for `PNG_.zip` files in hidden subdirectories of the bundle directories.

Comment: Thanks for the extremely detailed answer but  the results  of :

`printf '%s\n' **/*.bundle(/Ne'[() {(($#))} $REPLY/**/PNG_.zip(NY1)]')`

gets incorrect results and i  get  results  with PNG_.zip in them.

Comment: @user67486 My bad, I'd posted the code for the bundles _with_ the file, not the bundles _without_ the file. I've added a negation in the code.

Comment: Thank you so much. - looks perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I believe:

```
   $ find . -type f \(  ! -iname "*PNG_.zip*" \)
```

Does the trick. ! operator negates the search pattern. SO you get all files that do not match it.

Comment: It actually returns  anything that is not PNG_.zip and what i need is that it would return  any *.bundle in that folder that doesn't contain PNG_.zip